# count() function fails when reading data from Cassandra into pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am reading data from Cassandra as :

```
df = spark.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(**configs)\
    .options(table=tablename, keyspace=keyspace)\
    .option("ssl", True)\
    .option("sslmode", "require")\
    .load()
```

Now this df is pyspark dataframe. I able to perform show(), printSchema() function on this df but when I am printing

```
df.count()
```

it's throwing error:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o1394.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 19 in stage 
48.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 19.3 in stage 48.0 (TID 2053, js- 
56258-63801-i-32-w-1.net, executor 9): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
requirement failed: Column not found in Java driver Row: count
```

How I can resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your table?

Comment: Please add more information - what version of spark connector is used, how you did install it, etc.

Comment: I am using spark verison 2.4.8

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's not failing at the same stage all of the time. If that's the case, then you can try tuning the read/write parameters:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.4/doc/reference.md#read-tuning-parameters

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.4/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters

When you start pyspark, you'll need to pass the `--conf spark.cassandra.<option>` in.